# C# unable to find content of ASP.net Textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, findcontrol

Okay so I am trying to create a sort of registration wizard, so there are different sections within the asp such as the one below:

```
  <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a href="#addwizard" data-parent="#accordion-demo" data-toggle="collapse">
              Term Time Address
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="termaddy" class="panel-collapse collapse in"  runat="server">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <form id="form-termaddy" >
          <div class="main_input_box">
                 <div class="col-lg-6">

                    <div class="form-group">
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txttermhousenum" runat="server" placeholder="House Number" class="form-control" textmode="SingleLine"></asp:TextBox>
                         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="RequiredFieldValidator28" controltovalidate="housenum" errormessage="Required Field" display="Dynamic"/>
                 </div>

                   <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="main_input_box">
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtxtermstreet" runat="server" placeholder="Street" class="form-control"  textmode="SingleLine"></asp:TextBox>
                         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="RequiredFieldValidator29" controltovalidate="street" errormessage="Required Field" display="Dynamic"/>
                 </div>
                       </div>

                   <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="main_input_box">

                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtxtermpost" runat="server" placeholder="Postcode" class="form-control" textmode="SingleLine"></asp:TextBox>
                         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="RequiredFieldValidator31" controltovalidate="postcode" errormessage="Required Field" display="Dynamic"/>
                 </div>
                       </div>


                   </div>
               </div>
            </form>
          </div> <!--/.panel-body -->
        </div> <!-- /#addwizard -->
      </div> <!-- /.panel.panel-default -->
```

So whenever the user fills out the form and hits save. The c# gets the details of the text boxes and updates the db:

```
//term time address info
        string txttermhouse = ((TextBox)termaddy.FindControl("txttermhousenum")).Text;
        string txttermstr = ((TextBox)termaddy.FindControl("txtxtermstreet")).Text;
        string txttermpostcode = ((TextBox)termaddy.FindControl("txtxtermpost")).Text;

        termaddress(txttermhouse, txttermstr, txttermpostcode);
```

The issue is that when the code passes through this portion it sees each of the text boxes as blank and saves them in the db as and empty string. I have also tried directly referencing the textbox into the method, ie :

```
 termaddress(txttermhousenum.Text, txtxtermstreet.Text, txtxtermpost.Text);
```

But neither way seems to work. Any help on how to get the text box values would be greatly appreciated, very confused by this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a master page, make sure that you do not have two `<form runat="server">` tags. I've once experienced this issue and it was a result of that.

Comment: each part of the accordion had a form tag which was the issue it seems. Removing these tags has everything working.

Comment: So did my answer help? If it did, an upvote would do the trick. Happy coding.

Comment: Yeah you led me down the road of looking at the form tags so thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `Textbox` directly , no need of using of FindControl:

Try accessing them as follows

```
  string txttermhouse = txttermhousenum.Text;
  string txttermstr = txtxtermstreet.Text;
  string txttermpostcode = txtxtermpost.Text;
```

You can pass to your method as follows:

```
termaddress(txttermhouse , txttermstr , txttermpostcode );
```

Comment: @user4184963 where are you calling this , i mean on which event? and also show me your page_load method

Answer (score 0):

Why are you finding your controls using your `div` running at server? I would suggest you to remove `runat="server"` from your `div` if you are using it only to find controls. This makes your response slower.

You can simply access them as follows:

```
  string txttermhouse = txttermhousenum.Text;
  string txttermstr = txtxtermstreet.Text;
  string txttermpostcode = txtxtermpost.Text;
```

> You really don't need to find controls. You can access them directly.
>   You need to find control when its repeating inside grid column
>   template or within repeater etc., then you need to find control
>   otherwise you can access them directly.

Comment: as I mentioned about I tried your suggested approach. The c# still sees the textboxes as being empty

Comment: Can you please post your Page_Load event? Also in which event you are executing that code? Is it within update panel?